# Does There Need to be an Attempt?

Tags: discussion

I'm seeing a lot of questions where someone is essentially asking, "Can you perform this task for me?" Often it is, more specifically, "Please write a test to cover this code."

This form of question rankles me and I used to think there was something specifically in the [guidelines](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) about making an attempt first, but I do not see anything that says you should attempt to solve a problem before asking it, per se.

In my estimation, this type of question does not meet the **Search and Research** standard nor the **Make it Relevant to Others** standard. I am not sure, however, if I should flag these posts. If so, what flags apply?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I generally flag these for deletion and mark them as 'Too Broad'.  We all make a living using SF, I have no problem helping people out when they are stuck, but when people just ask us to write their code for them.....nope sorry.

I think too broad fits as well, because there is not one specific answer to a question of 'write this code for me'.  There are many possible answer that all could be correct in some way.  Think of all the different ways you could write a simple trigger that technically 'works' (Granted, some are much better than others, but they all might 'work').

You need to ask a more specific question about the code you have already written, or attempted to write.

Answer (score 10):

Flag for close / deletion, maybe along with a comment?