# Review low quality questions: What to choose for people asking to do their work

Tags: feature-request, review-queue, low-quality-posts

People often flag questions as low quality when the person didn't try anything already and is asking the community to do their work.

So when I try to review theses questions, I have these propositions:

- duplicate of...
- off-topic because...
- unclear what you're asking
- too broad
- primarily opinion-based

But sometimes, none of theses propositions can be related to the question.

In fact, even if the person didn't try anything, the question can be clear.

So my question is: Is it necessary to add a new proposition?

If not, what do I have to choose for this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might find this question I asked a couple years ago to be relevant: [Does There Need to be an Attempt?](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1916/does-there-need-to-be-an-attempt)

> I generally flag these for deletion and mark them as 'Too Broad'. We all make a living using SF, I have no problem helping people out when they are stuck, but when people just ask us to write their code for them.....nope sorry.

I also often would mark them as `Off Topic Because...` > `Questions on problems in code you've written must describe the`**`specific problem`**`...` It's a pretty similar reasoning to flagging it as too broad. It also ties in with the comment template I typically start out with:

> What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck!

If they're a new user, I typically preface that with:

> Hi @user, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: Thanks ! Sorry I couldn't find your previous question.

Comment: No worries, they get kind of buried after a while. Always glad to see conversations on Meta, and to have one recur just indicates to me that it's an important issue.